# thrown n dice and using IRV sum of face that do not appear on top

Tags: probability

Consider n dice are thrown simultaneously. Use indicator random variables to compute
the expected value of the sum of the faces that do not appear on top. E.g., if 4 appears on top
then the sum is 1+2+3+5+6=17, for 1 die. If there are 6 dice then what probability? and also with n dice

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What, for instance, is the expected value of the face that is on top?

Comment: Hint: If $X$ is this random variable for a single die, then evaluates as $X=21-D$ where $D$ is the random variable for the top face of the die.

Comment: No, sum of the the faces except top face, so I think for 6 dices I can do first and then for n dice @lulu

Comment: I think there's some ambiguity here. If I roll two dice, both come up $4$, is the sum we want $17$ or $34$?

Comment: I was asking you "what is the expected value of the face that is on top?"  I understand that this is not the answer to your question, though the answer you want can easily be worked out from it.  And I was only speaking of a single die, though passing from one die to six (or to any number) is easy.

Comment: It means if one time roll a dice 1 appear on top then sum would be 20, if 2 come up then the sum would be 19 and so on for other dices. so if we take all cases what's the probability for n dices thown?

Comment: You say "What's the probability for $n$ dice thrown?" Do you mean "What is the expected value for $n$ dice thrown?"

Comment: Look up the definition of [Expected Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) if you are not familiar with it.  You should have no trouble at all computing the expected value of the throw of a fair die.

Comment: it means we need to find  sum of faces except top face so when n dice are thrown what is the probability just do not consider expected value for now just look for probability for dice thrown @ThomasAndrews

Comment: I don't understand what is unclear to people here about this problem, OP included.  The way I read the question, we throw $n$ dice.  We look at the collection of faces which are shown on the dice.  If any faces are missing, we add the missing values together.  For instance, if we rolled eight dice and we got the results `1 1 3 3 3 4 5 5` we would add $2$ and $6$ since they were not included in the results and get a result of $8$ for our random variable.

Comment: As for approaching this, as the problem very rightly suggests and hints... look at the random variable in terms of indicator random variables.  What is the probability that among all $n$ of the dice, not a single one of them shows a `1`?  Similarly, what is the probability that among all $n$ of the dice, not a single one of them shows a `6`, etc...

Comment: The expected value of an indicator random variable for an event is just the probability of that
event. (Remember that a random variable IA is the indicator random variable for event A, if
IA = 1 when A occurs and IA = 0 otherwise (for reference)  @lulu

Comment: Yes, yes, we know what expected value is, and you apparently either know what it is or at least have access to a resource which says what it is.  Now...  the first step to the problem again is to express your random variable in terms of a linear combination of indicator random variables.  The second step is to calculate the probabilities for those indicator random variables.  The final step is just arithmetic.

Comment: Yes, but what can be the probability for 6 dice thrown? @JMoravitz

Comment: You do not appear to be reading what I am saying and are ignoring everything written... just going back to asking the same tired questions again wanting us to hold your hand through the problem or just straight up tell you the answer.  I refuse to answer your question until you first answer mine and follow along and understand what I am saying.  Your random variable can be written as a linear combination of indicator random variables.  Do you see how?  Do it.

Comment: A further push on how to do this... think of your random variable this way... "*If a 1 never appeared in any of my n dice, add 1 to my total.  If a 2 never appeared in any of my n dice, add 2 to my total.  If a 3 never appeared in any of my n dice, add 3 to my total, etc...*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading this as we roll all $n$ of our dice, we look at the collection of faces, we add the values of all numbers from $\{1,2,\dots,6\}$ which did not appear as a face for any of the dice.  So, for example, having rolled the eight dice `1 1 3 3 3 4 6 6` we are missing faces `2` and `5` so the sum would have been $7$.  Meanwhile having rolled just two dice and gotten `5 5` we are missing every value except $5$ and so our sum would have been $16$, etc...

Now... our random variable can be calculated in the following way:  Begin with a running total of $0$.  If a $1$ is not present as the upper face on any of the $n$ thrown dice, then add $1$ to our total.  Similarly, if a $2$ is not present as the upper face on any of the $n$ thrown dice, then add $2$ to our total.  Continue in this fashion for $3$, and on, if a value is not present as the upper face on any die add that value to our running total.

Recognize that these "*If this then add that*" statements can be written with indicator random variables and our random variable can be written as a linear combination of those indicator random variables.

Letting $X$ be our random variable and $X_i$ be the indicator random variable $X_i=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }i\text{ was not among the die results shown}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$, we have:

> $$X = X_1+2X_2+3X_3+\dots+6X_6$$

Now... we can look at $\Pr(X_1=1)$ and $\Pr(X_2=1)$ etc...

First, notice that $\Pr(X_1=1)=\Pr(X_2=1)=\dots=\Pr(X_6=1)$.  Next, recall what $\Pr(X_1=1)$ means.  It means that in our $n$ throws of the dice, no $1$'s occurred.  That means that in all $n$ throws of the dice, one of the five results different than $1$ occurred.

> $$\Pr(X_i=1)=\dfrac{5^n}{6^n}$$

Finally, remember that for indicator random variables we have that $E[X_i]=\Pr(X_i=1)$ and remember that expected value is linear so $E[\alpha A+\beta B] = \alpha E[A]+\beta E[B]$ for any scalars $\alpha,\beta$ and random variables $A,B$.  Complete the necessary algebra and arithmetic and reach your final conclusion.

Comment: This is really helpful

Comment: From your example, For eight dice roll how can be the sum is 7?

Comment: By the simple fact we *are not summing the dice*.  We are summing the missing values.

Comment: After so many discussion, I still don't understand **what is the expected value of the sum of the faces that do not appear on top?**

Comment: What is unclear about the above explanation? I gave all the setup for the problem and only left out the arithmetic which you should be able to do on your own